# php file_get_contents cannot read xml service

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I want to read and parse the xml data from an url.My url is:"http://xml.gamebookers.com/sports/bandy.xml".I can access xml data from browser.However,when i attempt to read it by using php it doesnt work.It errors like this:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://xml.gamebookers.com/sports/bandy.xml): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in

How can i fix this?Any comments on this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I whould suggest you do the following: Make sure the file exists at the url you are trying to open and get contents. Make sure the allow_url_fopen is ON.

Comment: The url is available because i can access it from browser and allow_url_fopen is on.I tried another solution like this:I use file_ get_contents with stream parameter(for proxy) and i used return value of file_get_contents in simplexml_load.However the return value of file_get_contents is string so simplexml_load had error because of string parameter instead of xml file parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705593/php-fopen-redirection-limit-reached-error/706237#706237) for an answer:

> This error is most likely connected to
>   too many (HTTP) redirects on the way
>   from your script to the file you want
>   to open. The [default redirection
>   limit should be 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705593/php-fopen-redirection-limit-reached-error/706237#706237). As 20
>   redirects are quite alot there could
>   be some error in the filename itself
>   (causing e.g. the webserver on the
>   other end to do some
>   spellcheck-redirects) or the other
>   server is misconfigured or there are
>   some security measures in place or...
>
> If you feel the need to extend the 20
>   redirects you could use a stream
>   context.

```
$context = array(
    'http'=>array('max_redirects' => 99)
);
$context = stream_context_create($context);
// hand over the context to fopen()
$data = file_get_contents('http://xml.gamebookers.com/sports/bandy.xml', false, $context);
// ...
```

Please see:

- [Streams](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php)
- [`stream_context_create()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)
- [HTTP context options](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)

Comment: Thanks Stefan i solved it by using curl with proxy options.I got the xml datas.However it is very slow.Is there any way to pass parameter to xml url ?For example:"http://xml.gamebookers.com/sports/bandy.xml?name=footbal"  ?I want to use such a function in order to filter result.I dont need whole result

Comment: No  - at least not if the XML file is really an XML file. If it's some sort of REST endpoint (which means there's a script running behind that URL) it might be possible to pass additional parameters to the URL. If it's just a file, it'll be downloaded as a file.

Answer (score 1):

Try the snippet:
 $request_url = 'http://xml.gamebookers.com/sports/bandy.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("feed not loading");

/*
Then just parsing out child node of your xml.
for example 
*/

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
      {
       echo $child->getName().":  ".$child."
";
      }

Hope this help

PS:  Open your PHP.INI and look for 
     allow_url_fopen = On   // make sure it is ON

Comment: Hi dbwebtek thanks for your care but i got following error: Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://xml.gamebookers.com/sports/bandy.xml): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /var/www/fbDemo/rss.php on line 13 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://xml.gamebookers.com/sports/bandy.xml" in /var/www/fbDemo/rss.php on line 13 feed not loading

Comment: By the way my application is in localhost and i am using proxy.Without proxy i cannot reach that xml service from browser

Comment: I used a stream like this(because i am using proxy):                      $default_opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar",
    'proxy'=>"tcp://myProxyIp:myPort"
  )
);                                                                and then i use        fie_get_contents() function with stream parameter and it worked.However is there any way to use stream parameter in simple_xml_load?

Comment: I just tested from my end with the code snippet and get the data back with show the DATE...so I guess it must be configuaration on your machine.  Mine is Ubuntu 10.04, full LAMP stacked